Question how to achieve this shape in flutter
how to achieve this shape in flutter
I have tried to draw this shape and the result with me was like this
my try
i don't know how to draw the rounded circular border
like in first image provided
build this shape in flutter
how to achieve this shape in flutter
my code


     Center(
                  child: ClipPath(
                    clipper: MyCustomClipper(),
                    child: Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.red,
                      ),
                      width: 200,
                      height: 200,
                      child: const Center(
                        child: Text(
                          'Clipped Container',
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),


class MyCustomClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    var path = Path();
    path.moveTo(30, 0);
    path.lineTo(size.width, 0);
    path.lineTo(size.width - 30, size.height);
    path.lineTo(0, size.height); // (3

    path.close();
    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) {
    return false;
  }
}




use roundPolygon

Just add Matrix4.skewX(yourValue) in your container.
Container(
height: 100,
width: 100,
transform: Matrix4.skewX(-0.3),
decoration: BoxDecoration(
borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
gradient: LinearGradient(
colors: [
Colors.green,
Colors.pink,
],
begin: Alignment.topCenter,
end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
),
),
),
